# How to bypass router in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

We have a few template files with their components. They also have their routes defined and called like:

```
<a routerLink="/Path-with-component"> Open page with component </a>
```

We also have **plain and static** `.html` files which strictly doesn't need any logic as such. So, we're calling them like:

```
<a href="Static-page.html">Open static page</a>
```

They always go through the router and the file is not called from the physical path.

So, we need them to not go through the Angular 2 router. How do we do this?

Comment: Add backslash before path ``href="/Static-page.html"``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally it should not go through router, unless you have defined a wild char route.

```
{ path: '**',  component: <some component>}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
  <hr />
    <a routerLink="/home" >Home</a>
    <a href='test.html'  >Static page</a>
  <hr />
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
class AppComponent { name = 'Angular'; }

@Component({
  template: `<h1>Home</h1>
  `
})
class HomeComponent { }

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3bhw9uMCAnxf1Y0TdJNZ?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!